# Issues with opening up four .bat scripts in ConEmu window with .bat code

Tags: batch-file, conemu

Made code to start four of my .bat scripts in one ConEmu window with .bat code but it has some issues and only opens up one of them.

Code:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal

set "ScriptDir=%~dp0"
set "ConEmuDir=%ScriptDir%\ConEmuPack.221218"

"%ConEmuDir%\ConEmu64.exe" -cmd ^
  call "%ScriptDir%\Modules\Auto\Auto Backup System\Auto Backup System.bat" ^
  -new_console:s ^
  call "%ScriptDir%\Modules\Auto\Auto Start Sm If Not Running\Auto Start Sm If Not Running.bat" ^
  -new_console:s ^
  call "%ScriptDir%\Modules\Manual\Manual Backup System\Manual Backup System.bat"

endlocal
```

When I open up the .bat script an console opens up and starts up ConEmu and only one of the scripts opened up. The console doesn't close for some reason like I wanted to, but also when I close the ConEmu window it says:

> ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? or Terminate batch job (Y/N)?